# How to get vertex eigenvalue centralities in R with igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I have a network loaded into an igraph object `G` that has 198 vertices and 214 edges.  If I run:

```
eig<-evcent(G)$vector
```

The resulting `eig` is a vector with 2172 elements, rather than 198 elements.   [The documentation on the package](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/evcent.html) claims it returns the "centralities of positions `v`."  Any ideas on how to get the eigenvalue centralities for each vertex?

Comment: I've only used igraph a little, but this usually works fine for me.  You might want to provide more information about G.  Can you provide a small example graph to reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was recently asked (and answered) on the mailing list.

Check out this thread "[Eigenvector Centrality](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2009-11/msg00042.html)" thread. It looks like a recompile of the R/igraph library might be in order, but should be rather straight forward.

Comment: That thread has another problem that I forgot to mention: the centralities reported are all < 0.  I will try this approach, though I have yet to recompile anything in R + MacOS X before.

Comment: Compiling R on mac is very easy. Just make sure you have the latest version of XCode for your OS, and grab and install the gfortran installer from here (igraph doesn't use fortran, but other packages do): http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/gfortran-4.2.3.dmg

Comment: It would be nice to know if a recompile fixes this issue.  As of R2.10.1 on MacOS X, the options parameter to evcent(...), documented here http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/evcent.html, ignores most anything you throw in there, including the $start setting mentioned in the forum post.

Comment: I don't think the thread explains the behavior, actually.  The thread talks about conditions under which the "wrong" eigenvector is found; the current question is about why a result with an unexpected form (2172 elements rather than 198 elements) is returned.